# How to add hyperlinks in my comments?

Tags: support

I've seen others do it but am unable to figure out how to do it myself.

I've tried using this approach:

`[Word][1]

 [1] : http://google.com`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The format you were trying is Markdown's footnote link style. In order to put links in comments you must use the inline style. This also works in questions and answers. In order to make an inline link, you put the text of the hyperlink in square brackets, then immediately follow it by the URL in parenthesis: `[link title](link url)`.

Alternatively, if you are linking to questions & answers on Stack Exchange, the easiest way is to install the [Comment Link AutoPrettifier](https://stackapps.com/questions/2378/comment-link-autoprettifier) script which automatically converts raw URL's in your comments to pretty links using the title of the post being linked.

Comment: [Shameless self promotion in the name of testing.](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/users/1568/monika-michael)

Comment: Works! Thanks :)

Comment: Nice edit! ROFL ;p

Comment: @MonikaMichael: Your welcome. Also for anybody who doesn't know the dirty little secret: moderators can actually edit anyone's comments. We tend to use it very sparingly, but I do use it to cleanup URL's sometimes. With the userscript I linked above, I can just hit edit, then save again on people's comments to fix the link titles to SE posts. Beyond that it doesn't get used much except to occasionally put words in people's mouth as I just did for Monika above :)